# Constant, random or timezone-dependent expressions in (sub)partitioning function are not allowed

Tags: mysql, hash

mytable like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `test1` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `project_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `md5` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `create_time` datetime NOT NULL,
    `update_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`project_id`,`md5`),
    KEY `index_id` (`md5`),
) ;
```

I want to partition by `md5` and `project_id`。
so I create a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f2(md5 VARCHAR(255), project_id int(11))
RETURNS int
return MOD(md5, 10) + project_id;
```

When I partitioning this table use this sql:

```
ALTER TABLE test1 PARTITION BY HASH(f2(md5, project_id)) PARTITIONS 100;
```

it shows:

> Constant, random or timezone-dependent expressions in (sub)partitioning function are not allowed.

But the answer is not Constant, random and timezone-dependent.  So I do not know how to do with id, who can help me ? thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you browse the MySQL documentation on [hash partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-hash.html), you will see that certain constructs are [prohibited for partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-limitations.html):

> Prohibited constructs.  The following constructs are not permitted in partitioning expressions:
>
> Stored procedures, **stored functions**, **UDFs**, or plugins.
> Declared variables or user variables.

For a workaround, try just inlining the logic behind your UDF function:

```
ALTER TABLE test1 PARTITION BY HASH(MOD(md5, 10) + project_id) PARTITIONS 100;
```

Even if a function could be made to work, it would probably not be that performant, and a direct expression is a better way to go.

Comment: thank you for answering me, but I tried your sql early, it failed to :                                                         
     ERROR 1491 (HY000): The PARTITION function returns the wrong type